# Do the policies that Ben Shapiro supports align with those of the Alt-Right?

Tags: policy, ideology, conservatism, alt-right

The Economist released a headline labeling him as alt-right before retracting the statement due to heavy criticism from Shapiro himself and other conservatives [1](https://dailycaller.com/2019/03/28/ben-shapiro-economist-alt-right/)
. He has rejected this label and said that as an Orthodox Jew, he is actually one of the most hated public personas by the alt-right community.

This question is not about if Ben Shapiro is alt-right or supports their policies more than with any other political faction, it just asks whether any opinions that he has expressed align with alt-right consensus.

Comment: "...it just asks whether any opinions that he has expressed align with alt-right consensus." It is unlikely that anyone has never expressed some view that is commonly held by "alt-right" people (whatever you mean by that). The question that's worth asking is whether or not he agrees with any of the positions that *are distinctive to alt-right groups*. To that end, how you define "alt-right" and what you consider its defining positions to be is crucial to answering that question.

Comment: After some thought, I don't think there's any productive way forward with this question. This question would be just as problematic if it were asking if Bernie Sanders were aligned with Anti-Fa. The question, possibly unintentionally, is baiting for an association between Shapiro and an extremist group that he explicitly rejects. Any answer must minimize the differences between Shapiro's positions and the alt-right's, no matter how significant those differences are. Doing so *decreases* understanding of our political landscape, contrary to the site's stated goals, and increases polarization.

Comment: @jpmc26 Didn't mean to bait at all, I watch Ben Shapiro myself because he makes good points sometimes(not the open sewage tweet of course), and I do not identify as alt-right myself. Also it's really fun watching him "debate" the most uneducated college students he could find, but that's a whole different discussion. It's already clear that Ben Shapiro is not alt-right, especially because he is not white-supremacist, anti-Semitic, or isolationist, all positions that are **distinctive to alt-right groups** like you have mentioned. It's still beneficial to see what policies **do** overlap.

Comment: I would also say that this question can be answerable, the answer would just need to be far better supported with evidence of both Shapiro and multiple different alt-right figures of their beliefs. I'm beginning to think that the admins just saw the "What do you think?" part of the original post and put this on hold, as if politics is supposed to be based in empirical fact that can be proven with a couple of theorems. While the definition of alt-right varies with who you ask, there are still policies that most if not all of them support.

Comment: @ChickenWingGeek Understood. The hard part of that is nailing down what *other* positions alt-righters actually advocate, as I alluded to in my previous comment. The only real definition that anyone can seem to remotely agree on is "white supremicists," which is the defining characteristic that you say Shapiro doesn't share. For an example of the difficulty, D'Souza asserts that in economic matters, such as universal healthcare, many of them are more aligned with typically progressive policies. But is that a distinctively alt-right position? Few would argue so. *That's* why it got closed.

Comment: Like any political group, there is undoubtedly internal variation. So it's not really clear what defines them beyond their unifying policy perspectives.

Comment: @jpmc26 while not as white and black(**no pun intended**) as if someone is a "white supremacist", most if not all of rightists which criticize and reject mainstream republicanism for being not conservative enough do so because either 1. It does not isolationist, 2. It is too politically correct, or 3. It is too egalitarian in terms of accepted peoples and social rights

Comment: @ChickenWingGeek I don't understand if you are saying that opponents of "republicanism" are alt-right or not, which illustrates the problem. And this is coming from a pretty right wing person who would probably vote for Shapiro if he ran. I get what you're trying to say, but there really isn't a good answer that can be established. While mathematical rigor isn't required, *some* kind of basis in fact is, and "alt-right" is not a clear cut term and is not readily associated with many specific positions.

Comment: @jpmc26, sorry, meant mainstream republican(as in gop) viewpoints.

Comment: If you're really seeking information, my advice would be to post a new question; edits that invalidate existing answers are heavily frowned upon. But in the new one, instead of asking about "alt-right" positions, instead *name specific positions of Shapiro's you're interested in finding out*. Or if you understand Shapiro's positions, come at it from the other direction: name specific individuals or groups you consider "alt-right" and ask about specific positions of theirs. In other words, make it clear cut what you're looking for. Also make sure to do your own research first.

Comment: I'd also suggest that in such a new question, leave the term "alt-right" out of it. It's such a charged term that it will readily invite controversy no matter who it identifies, what it means, or how you use it. Someone will either be offended or will want to promote their personal witty (in their eyes) take on the matter. (Trust me. It's a temptation I personally have to stave off and don't always succeed at, and it's one people interested in politics are especially susceptible to.)

Comment: @jpmc26 Thanks for the feedback, I'm sort of new to stack exchange(well, actually engaging in it) and politics especially.

Answer (score 10):

**To some extent, yes.**

It's quite difficult to define what the alt-right is, since few people use that label for themselves. Per Wikipedia, [here are some of the common positions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt-right) of the alt-right:

> The alt-right is a white nationalist, racist movement. Part of its
>   membership supports **anti-immigrationist policies** to ensure a continued
>   white majority in the United States. Others call for the breakup of
>   the country to form a white separatist ethno-state in North America.
>   Some alt-rightists seek to make white nationalism socially respectable
>   in the U.S., while others—known as the "1488" scene—adopt **openly white
>   supremacist and neo-Nazi stances.** Some alt-rightists are anti-semitic,
>   promoting a conspiracy theory that there is a Jewish plot to bring
>   about white genocide; other alt-rightists view most Jews as members of
>   the white race. The alt-right is **anti-feminist, advocates for a more
>   patriarchal society,** and intersects with the men's rights movement and
>   other sectors of the online manosphere. Alt-rightists generally
>   support anti-interventionist and isolationist foreign policies
>   alongside economic protectionism and thus criticise mainstream U.S.
>   conservatism. Attitudes to social issues like homosexuality and
>   abortion vary within the movement. Individuals aligned with many of
>   the alt-right's ideas but not its white nationalism have been termed
>   "alt-lite".

Early adopters of the label alt-right (or "alternative right") include Richard Spencer, a neo-Nazi white nationalist, and Paul Gottfried, a "paleoconservative" who has very strong conservative opinions but doesn't seem to be particularly affiliated with white nationalism, anti-feminism, or other such philosophies. But they don't necessarily define what the alt-right is today. I think the definition given previously is a fair broad strokes characterization of the alt-right, so that's mostly what I'll be comparing it to.

**So, how do Ben Shapiro's views compare?**

- Shapiro is anti-Muslim and anti-Arab. He said that "We're above 800 million Muslims who are radicalized – more than half the Muslims on earth. That's not a minority... the myth of the tiny radical Muslim minority is just that: it's a myth." He also [claimed](https://twitter.com/benshapiro/status/25712847277) that "Israelis like to build. Arabs like to bomb crap and live in open sewage. This is not a difficult issue." This aspect of his views aligns with the alt-right, particularly with respect to their anti-immigration and white nationalist beliefs.
- Shapiro doesn't express overt white nationalist views, but does dismiss racism, having suggested that black people don't face more obstacles than white people in the US, and has asserted that racial wealth disparaties are unrelated to racism. He has also advocated in favor of the Confederate flag. These aspects of his opinions align with the white nationalist beliefs of the alt-right.
- Shapiro is generally anti-LBGTQ. He's characterized transgender people as having a "mental illness." He believes that same-sex intercourse is immoral and that gay families are worse than families with a mother and a father. Although the Wikipedia definition notes that opinions on homosexuality "vary" among alt-right believers, since LBGTQ rights are heavily associated with the feminist beliefs that the alt-right generally rejects, much of the alt-right is hostile to LBGT people.
- He's also strongly opposed to left-wing groups, criticizing, for instance, the membership of university professors in "leftist parties." The title of one of his books literally is about "destroying" leftists in argument. Although this view is obviously not unique to the alt-right, it nonetheless aligns strongly with them.
- He is anti-feminist, saying that "radical feminism" (among other things) has "destroyed the foundation of our own greatness." This aligns, obviously, with the anti-feminism of the alt-right. He's also advocated for traditional gender roles, saying, for instance, that "As a society, we have robbed men of their protective missions," another opinion that aligns strongly with the alt-right.
- Shapiro is *not* aligned with the common anti-Semitic stances of the alt-right, which is perhaps unsurprising considering his Jewish background.
- He is also *not* aligned with the common isolationist and anti-interventionist stances. For instance, in 2005 he wrote an article titled "Why the Iraq War is right for America."

So Ben Shapiro's opinions have significant overlap with the alt-right, particularly with regard to racism, anti-feminism and belief in traditional masculinity, and anti-LBGTQ opinions, as well as a fixation on "leftists." They don't overlap as far as outright white nationalism or isolationism and particularly not with respect to anti-Semitism.

Comment: It's worth noting that people's opinions can change over 14 years of time. Do you have a more modern source for his interventionist stances?

Comment: @nick012000 - No, unfortunately. But the information might be out there.

Comment: Your answer lacks supporting sources for these positions.

Comment: I'd like to offer my apologies for the debating in these comments. I was frustrated, and rather than attack the reason for that frustration directly, I disputed this answer. Please see my most recent comment on the question for a more accurate representation of what I see as the problem here, though I do think this answer's presentation contributes to that problem rather than helps alleviate it.

Comment: [Here](https://www.dailywire.com/news/4421/flashback-shapiro-myth-tiny-radical-muslim-chase-stephens) is the source I linked in a now deleted comment for your quote about "radicalized" Muslims if you still wish to edit sources into your answer. I highly recommend that you do so, and I highly recommend your readers examine the full presentation for context, definition of terms, and other matters of clarity.